# Creating a password for the mysql root account has caused problems in WAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, wamp, sqlbuddy

I have created a new password for the root account using:

```
    mysqladmin -u root password "[newpassword]"
```

This caused problems with connecting to phpmyadmin which I solved by changing the config.inc.php file at the lines containing:

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '[newpassword]';
```

This solved that issue. However, I still am getting a 'FORBIDDEN' error when trying to connect to sqlbuddy and webgrind. Are there equivalent ways to solving these problems? Or what would be the correct way to going about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

SQLBuddy asks for a Userid/Password when you run it, unless you have changed the config.php file to use a defaultpassword.

Are you keying the correct password??

Comment: Explain what you mean by 'keying'?

I also realized I would have to change/add something to the config.php but I am unsure what that would be?

Comment: keying == entering